# gradle - classnotfoundexception - ToolResolver

Tags: java, exception, gradle

I've recently updated the gradle version in a project to 2.13. Since doing so attempts to run any builds, tests, whatnot give me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/gradle/platform/base/internal/toolchain/ToolResolver
> org.gradle.platform.base.internal.toolchain.ToolResolver

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/platform/base/internal/toolchain/ToolResolver
```

The only gradle reference to *ToolResolver* appears to be in the Java plugin. Is it possible that the plugin is corrupted somehow?

Suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade Gradle to the latest version

Comment: AFAICT 2.13 is the latest version